# Excess eventviewer noise from scardsvr

Tags: smartcard, event-viewer

I want to remove this excess noise from EventViewer.  I am running on Windows XP.  I keep getting:

> The description for Event ID ( 2 ) in Source ( SCardSvr ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: scredir.dll, The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E).

I have removed all of the smartcard dlls and exes from system32.  I have also searched the registry for scardsvr and scredir.dll and made sure there were no references.  However something in my system still insists on flooding my event viewer with these messages.  How can I find the source dll or exe that is shoving this gargage in?  Is there a definitive way of tracing the source executable "file" that is responsible?  Somewhere in my system, I know there is still a reference to the string SCardSvr".  I know this because when I launch the event viewer GUI, Right click on the Application node, then select View,Filter..., on the field, 'Event source:", one of the enumerations in the list is SCardSvr, so somewhere in the bowels of this OS, there is something still referencing this String.  Where is this event viewer list contained?  What file?

Comment: Off topic here, you might want to disable the certificate propagation service though. Please comment if this is the answer, I'll then flag it for migration. Needless to say, you should not delete registry keys/values without reason or without knowing the exact consequences.

Comment: I didn't find anything specifically called "certificate propagation service".  Is it called something else in SCM?

Should I have used superuser or serverfault???  I was really hoping for some sort of programmatic tool way of tracing down to a dll, exe, or registry reference exactly what is responsible for putting these messages in Event Viewer.  My reasoning for deleting reg keys:  this copy of XP is a VM instance I am trying to trim down for development purposes.  I do not have any smartcard hardware on it, so I read another page on how to trim unneeded services.